# Matlab use filepath in variable for textread

Tags: matlab

I can't make this piece of Code to work

```
for i = 1:length(names)
 distrfile = ls(strcat('./sample_distributions/sample-distribution_',names{i}(6:end),'*.csv'));
 [threadlength, frequency] = textread(distrfile,'%d %d', 'delimiter', ',');
end
```

the value I get for distrfile is not empty nor does it reference a file which does not exist. I am also in the correct working directory. If I manually paste the value of distrfile into the Code like

```
 [threadlength, frequency] = textread('distribution_44_start_50_end_100.csv','%d %d', 'delimiter', ',');
```

then it is working. I have however no idea what object String or whatever thing is contained in my distrfile variable since I have never worked with matlab. I can only guarantee that the console output of this variable points to a file which DOES exist but I get the following error :

??? Error using ==> textread at 167
   File not found.

Error in ==> threadsplot at 65
    [threadlength, frequency] = textread(distrfile,'%d %d', 'delimiter',
    ',');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the `ls` command through MATLAB returns a `char` value with an additional, whitespace in the end of `distrfile`. Try this (to discard final empty char before reading with textread):

```
distrfile = distrfile(1:end-1);
```

This is probably caused by MATLAB involking `unix` command, inside `ls`:

```
[~,file_name] = unix(['ls', file_name]);
```

You can alternatively use `dir`, instead of `ls`, and get the file name using the `.name` field of the resulting struct:

```
distrfile = dir(file_name);
[threadlength, frequency] = textread(distrfile.name,'%d %d', 'delimiter', ',');
```

Note: Other than these, you can pass directly `file_name` to `textread` (no need to `ls` since your outer loop indexes a single, known `file_name` at each iteration).

Comment: thanks a thousand times!!! I suspected that it contains a newline character at the end but not a whitespace...

Comment: regards your Note : the filename is not completely known though. It can vary in the part denoted with the * character